# PDO query not inserting and no error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to execute this code but my code dies because it is not able to insert into the table for some reason.the error given is "there was an error in storing to table" I have looked over my code but cannot see anything wrong with my PDO insert into query nor php error log.

```
try {
        $result = $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
                'Key' => "uploads/{$name_of_uploaded_file}",
                'Body' => fopen($path_of_uploaded_file, 'rb'),
                'ACL' => 'public-read'
            ]);

            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'])){
                  //send items to pending database

                  //inserts in pending db
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO pending (id,photo,title,description,name,pLike,pDislike) VALUES ('', :photo, :title, :description, :name, :pLike, :pDislike)";
                  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                  $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':photo', $result);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':description', $story);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $first_name);
                  $stmt->bindValue(':pLike', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                  $stmt->bindValue(':pDislike', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                  $stmt->execute();       
            }else {
                die("there was an error in storing to table");        
            }

        //remove the file
            unlink($path_of_uploaded_file);
    } catch(S3Exception $e){
        die("there was an error");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It already says in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php):

> Returns TRUE if the file named by **filename** was uploaded via HTTP POST.
>
> For proper working, the function is_uploaded_file() needs an argument like
>
> `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`,
>
> the name of the uploaded file on the client's machine `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` does not work.

Right now, you're pointing into the `size` index:

```
is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']
                                        // ^
```

Should be:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])){
```

Comment: ok so i changed what you recommended but it gave me this error: Call to a member function prepare() on null on line 129. Is this because (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])) is null?

Comment: You know what I had a very rookie mistake on mypart. On the prepare should have been pdo instead of conn. Sorry about that and thanks so much for helping me clarify

Comment: @user4589398 oh, so its suppposed to be `$pdo` lol :D typo errors. glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO pending (id,photo,title,description,name,pLike,pDislike) VALUES ('', :photo, :title, :description, :name, :pLike, :pDislike)";
                  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                  $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':photo', $result);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':description', $story);
                  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $first_name);
                  $stmt->bindValue(':pLike', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                  $stmt->bindValue(':pDislike', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                  $stmt->execute();     
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'error in query:  '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

In the first part of your if statement will echo the error in your query (if any)